# Move category description below post list in blog

Tags: php, categories, themes, description

i am good looking for a way to move - in blog page - the category description under the post list instead of above by default.

Can i do that with a php function without changing the theme files ?

thanks a lot

Comment: You would need to edit the template files. It's not possible to rearrange template files from functions.php.

Comment: I figured is was possible with filter and action, is'int it ?

Comment: No. Not unless the theme author specifically added their own hooks for you to use. That's very uncommon. You would need to check with the theme author. The proper way to modify theme templates is to use a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Answer (score 0):

The possibility to use actions to change template layout depends on the theme you're using. If the template consists of partials which are added via action hook, then you could remove the default functions attached to it and add them back in any order you want.

But if the layout is hardcoded in the template file, then your only option is to edit the file - i.e. copy it to a child theme and make modficiations to that copied file.